# Scalar minimization using scipy (`minimize` vs `minimize_scalar`)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a polynomial function for which I would like to find all local extrema. I can evaluate the polynomial via `P(x)` and to its derivative via `d_P(x)`.

My first thought was to use `minimize_scalar`, however this does not seem to be able to take advantage of the fact that I can evaluate the derivative. Alternatively, I can use the more general `minimize` function and provide the gradient.

Is there a rule of thumb about which method will work better, or is this something where I should test out both methods and see what works better. Since the function I am optimizing is a polynomial (well behaved) I wonder if it really matters so much which I use, but if someone has a more background that would be great.

In particular, `P(x)` is the (unique) polynomial of degree `n` which alternatively attains a value of `1` or `-1` on a set of `n-1` points.

Here is a sample of the `P(x)` scaled so that `P(0)=1`. Note that the y axis is plotted on a symlog scale.
[image]

Comment: can you share a plot of `P(x)` vs `x`

Comment: There will be many different `P(x)`. At each step `P(x)` will be an approximation to the minimax polynomial on a set of disjoint intervals.

Comment: But they can still be plotted in a 2D plot for range of x. Can you share with us a plot? Better yet the question can be edited to have `P(x)` and its domain.

Comment: For this function `minimize` may actually be better with the gradient specified may actually be better. This is because the function is smooth apart from the last interval where you have a discontinuity (lt->x- (dP/dx) != lt->x+ (dP/dx). There `minimize_scalar` may do a better job. But you probably are better off testing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a continuous scalar function, the documentation of `minimize_scalar` suggests a more discrete optimization approach. Since it doesn't use gradient information you won't have trouble with noise/discontinuities/discreteness in your objective. However, if you use `minimize` in conjunction with a gradient based method then you will have trouble with convergence for noise/discontinuities/discreteness.

If the objective function is fist order continuous then both `minimize` and `minimize_scalar` should yield the same solution for a given bound.